# Missing dependancies of rtree

Tags: python, spyder

I am currently using Spyder for Python, and I have this error message when I open the program:
Error:
You have missing dependencies!

rtree>= 0.8.3: None (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message.

Note: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, however to have a smooth experience, we strongly recommend.

I tried pip install rtree and got:

```
Collecting rtree
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1d/42d6904a436076df813d1df632575529991005b33aa82f169f01750e39e4/Rtree-0.9.3.tar.gz (520kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 522kB 467kB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\gitte\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gitte\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\\rtree\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gitte\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\\rtree\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\gitte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\rtree\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\gitte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\rtree\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import rtree
      File "C:\Users\gitte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\rtree\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .index import Rtree
      File "C:\Users\gitte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\rtree\rtree\index.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import core
      File "C:\Users\gitte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmbt5h2t\rtree\rtree\core.py", line 128, in <module>
        raise OSError("could not find or load %s" % lib_name)
    OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please advise what I can do.  Spyder works great so far, I just don't want to have issues along the way.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could just search for it... Have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179706/installing-rtree-on-windows-64-bits).

Comment: Unfortunately that link isn't helping, but thank you for trying.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) By using pip to install/update Spyder in Anaconda, you basically broke Anaconda and now you have to completely remove it and reinstall it. You also need to remove the directory where pip install packages, which usually is: `C:\Users\<your user>\Appdata\Roaming\Python`.

Comment: Hi Carlos.  I've done as you suggested.  Now that I've reinstalled it, I'm being told it has to be updated.  Per the instructions, can you confirm this is what I should do?

Updating Spyder
If you installed Spyder through Anaconda (recommended), WinPython, MacPorts, or your system package manager, update using those same methods. With Anaconda, just run (in Anaconda Prompt if on Windows) conda update anaconda to update the distribution as a whole and conda update spyder to update Spyder specifically.

Comment: Hello again.  I have updated anaconda, with conda update anaconda, and it appears successful, but it did not update Spyder.  I still see alert messages when I start the program that I need to download 4.0?  Can I simply ignore or will this cause problems later down the line?  I think trying to manually update Spyder is what got me into this mess.  At the moment, no rtree errors, or kernel errors.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Rtree requires libspatialindex (https://libspatialindex.org) which is not automatically installed. It seems some devs are aware of the problem and working on a fix:

https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/146
https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/147

Comment: This still solved the issue for me with Spyder 5 & Python 3.10.

Answer (score 6):

Came here with same problem, I don't use `conda` and could not install `libspatialindex` with `pipenv`:

```
# macOS Mojave 10.14.5
# python 3.7.4 (via pyenv)

Error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/r7/2sx1wsvx0gj5x43wkmymg61w0000gq/T/tmpn09357tzbuild/rtree/
```

Found [solution](http://macappstore.org/spatialindex/) — install `spatialindex` via Homebrew:

```
brew install spatialindex
```

Then `pipenv install rtree` succeeded and now `geopandas` works smoothly
Hope it'll help

Comment: I used `conda install libspatialindex` then `pip install rtree` and it worked. Yay!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this same problem and tried to all the solutions shown in this page. But failed.

Finally, i find the solution that is...

1. run the anaconda-navigator at the base.
2. Click and activate the environment what you want to fix
3. At the right search bar, type the 'rtree' and you can see the installed 'rtree' which has the version at 0.9.3 maybe.
4. Click the small green checkbox on the left of 'rtree' in Name tab then put your mouse cursor over the 'mask for specific installation' menu.
5. Click version '0.8.3' to downgrade via the anaconda-navigator.

after then, i executed spyder and the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Please execute the following command if you are using Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge rtree=0.9.3
```

Though I had rtree version 0.9.7, Spyder couldn't detect it. So I had to manually downgrade it.

Answer (score 2):

The following command fixed this issue for me:

conda update --all

Answer (score 1):

I also came here with the same problem. In my case (`Ubuntu2004` and `Python 3.8`), when I tried to install `spyder 4.2.1` with `conda install spyder`, problem with `rtree` still persisted.

However, when I checked its installation with `conda list rtree`. It has shown its successful installation with `version 0.9.7`. Despite it, I have also tried to install `rtree` package with both `pip` or `conda`. None of it had worked out.

Afterwards, I have tried a different installation command (basically, with different conda channel), then, this problem disappeared. Note that below it uses `conda-forge` channel to download the spyder.

```
conda create --name spy42py38 python==3.8
conda install spyder=4.2.1 -c conda-forge
```

Comment: I used the following steps for mac (Without anaconda installed): 1. select python interpreter (should be /usr/local/bin/python3.9)  2. brew install spatialindex    3.pip install spyder-kernels (refer python docs)

Answer (score 1):

I got this message after updating linux mint anaconda with `conda --update all`. When the suggested methods for installing the missing package gave a message that all of the necessary dependencies were already installed.

I used `conda list --revisions`, to list revisions, and then `conda install --revision N` where `N` is the next to last revision, in my case revision `10`.  This solved the problem. Revision 11 was the culprit.

I noticed it contains a new spyder kernal.

Comment: Finally discovered that by using anaconda navigator to downgrade rtree version 9 to rtree version 8.3 the error message went away.  Now able to use python 3.8 with spyder with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps for mac. We can do it without anaconda as well:

1. select python interpreter (should be /usr/local/bin/python3.9)
2. brew install spatialindex (homebrew should be installed)

3.pip install spyder-kernels (refer python docs)